# Why do photodiode transimpedance amplifiers care about signal frequency?

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, ac-dc, bandwidth

I'm designing a circuit to amplify low light levels (in the range of 0.1 uW) of measured black body radiation for application in a pyrometer. I don't have much experience with this kind of stuff so I've been looking online for example circuits to help me get the most accurate measurement. All of the examples I've seen include capacitors to stabilize the circuit and talk about the bandwidth of the circuit. I was under the impression that my photodiode would produce DC current, and I can't think of an example in which the photodiode would produce AC current, so why do all these circuits on the internet talk so much about the bandwidth? I've attached one of the example circuits below.

[image]

What is the purpose of C1 for DC current, and why would I care about the bandwidth of this circuit at all?

Side question: I plan to take measurements of the output voltage at 14 Hz, does this mean that the time constant for my circuit must support that measurement frequency?

Comment: If you plan to sample at 14 Hz you should limit your bandwidth to less than 7 Hz per the sampling theorem.

Answer (score 1):

A photodiode *will* produce an AC signal (on top of a DC signal) if exposed to an AC stimulus -- e.g. a signal that is (amplitude) modulated.

Even if you aren't using it this way, you still need to ensure your amplifier circuit is stable -- else it will oscillate on its own.

C1 stabilizes the amplifier -- you likely won't have a problem making the 3dB point above 14 Hz.

C2 reduces noise at the '+' input. It doesn't affect AC response.

Comment: I think where my understanding fails is how the term AC is used. I understand AC as current that varies direction. Although I will be measuring varying current, it will always be in the same direction, so it seemed reasonable to analyze it as DC current of varying magnitude. Is this not the correct way of thinking?

Comment: In this context, AC also means when there is AC superimposed on DC -- e.g. a varying (alternating) DC level. This DC level is called 'bias' -- basically because the diode cannot generate a negative current, by offsetting the value, you can still process the signal by separating the (no information content) DC portion from the 'useful' AC portion.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. I have two follow up questions on that note if you could answer them. First, to separate the DC portion out, I would want to employ a high-pass filter in my feedback loop since DC is zero frequency, correct? Second, I'm confused why you say that DC is "no information content", it is still some measure of current magnitude, why do you think that I should not care about that?

Comment: Actually, you seem to want to measure the DC component up to some frequency (e.g. not 'pure' DC). So you need the amplifier DC-coupled (you have that) and for it to have sufficient bandwidth to process the signals up to the frequency of interest (14 Hz ?) -- which seems quite low. So you still need a LOW pass filter (DC up to some frequency). 
'Information' implies something is changing (with time). In pure technical terms, 'DC' means constant.

Answer (score 1):

Such a transimpedance amplifier can be unstable due to the photodiode's capacitance, and other stray capacitances at the op-amp's input. C1's role is usually compensation to stabilise the system, which it does by reducing gain at higher frequencies.

When the photodiode is expected to operate at high frequency, C1 must be small enough to prevent undue attenuation at frequencies of interest, but still be large enough to produce stability. This is why bandwidth is such an important consideration.

However, in your application, which is operating at very low frequency (close to DC even) C1's role becomes two-fold. By deliberately reducing amplifier bandwidth, you eliminate noise at frequencies beyond some cut-off frequency. Every element in the system is a source of noise, much of which can be mitigated if you choose C1 carefully, to attenuate as wide a band of noise as possible.

From a frequency perspective, your sampling rate of 14 samples per second suggests that you are not interested in frequency components above 7Hz. From a sampling perspective, it suggests that you would like the amplifier to settle (following some change in illumination) in about \$\frac{1}{14Hz} = 70ms\$. These are just two ways of looking at the same phenomenon, but from the way you described your application, I think it makes more sense to approach choosing C1 from the perspective of settling time.

I would choose C1 to allow my amplifier to settle into a steady condition in less time than the interval between consecutive samples, 70ms. It's a good rule of thumb that an \$RC\$ filter will settle to within 1% of its final value after a time \$5RC\$ seconds:

$$ 5 \times R_1 \times C_1 = 70ms $$

Of course, any value of \$C_1\$ smaller than whatever you calculate here will work, and settle faster, but I recommend keeping it as *high* as possible, in order to subdue troublesome noise above the cut-off frequency:

$$ f = \frac{1}{2\pi R_1 C_1} $$

---

Since this circuit is deriving the diode's bias potential from the power supply (using R2 and R3), any fluctuation in that supply will appear at the op-amp's input. Naturally this will make its way to the output, becoming a part of your measurement.

To mitigate this, the designer includes C2, whose role is to keep bias potential steady in spite of power supply variations. It's not ideal, because it's just another filter, working well above some cut-off frequency, but not very effective below that.

The cut-off frequency of this source of \$V_B\$ is

$$ f = \frac{1}{2\pi (R_2 \parallel R_3)C_2} $$

Again, it's probably more useful to think in terms of settling time. The larger \$C_2\$, the longer it will take for \$V_B\$ to settle, but this delay only occurs once after application of power. It just means that you shouldn't trust measurements taken before you are sure that \$V_B\$ is stable.

Using the 5RC rule of thumb again, if you are happy to wait 100ms following power-on, before you start taking readings, then:

$$ 5 \times (R_2 \parallel R_3) \times C_2 = 100ms $$

If you are confident that your power supply is stable and consistent, containing negligible noise at frequencies below that cut-off, then this approach is fine. Otherwise you need to employ a well regulated, precise  voltage source, such as the [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf), to obtain \$V_B\$.

As an example of why R2/R3/C2 might not be good enough to derive \$V_B\$, consider if the supply were (as shown in your schematic) a battery. Over time it will discharge, causing the supply potential to slowly fall, slower than C2 can compensate for. This slow drift will appear in your measurements at the op-amp's output.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. I realized I made a typo in my initial question, I plan to take measurements at 1-14 MHz, as opposed to Hz. So for a gain of ~1,000,000 my C1 capacitance will have to be very low and will therefore lower my cut-off frequency. I'm considering using multi-stage amplification to solve this issue, does that seem reasonable?